# System.ServiceModel with .NET 2.0 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: wcf, windows-7, .net-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2

A project in .NET Framework 2.0 using System.ServiceModel does not compile on a Windows 7 machine, but compiles on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine. Can you explain why?

The project file Test1.vbproj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="IService1.vb" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />
</Project>
```

The IService1.vb:

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
<ServiceContract()> Public Interface IService1
    <OperationContract()> Function Function1() As String
End Interface
```

On a Windows 7 32bit machine this project does not compile, displaying the error messages:

Type 'OperationContract' is not defined.
Type 'ServiceContract' is not defined.

On a Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit machine this project compiles successfully.

The project opened on the Windows 7 machine:

[image]

The project opened on the Windows Server 2008 R2 machine:

[image]

The .NET frameworks installed on the Windows 7 machine:

[image]

The .NET frameworks installed on the Windows Server 2008 R2 machine:

[image]

The Windows features on  the Windows 7 machine:

[image]

The Windows features on  the Windows Server 2008 R2 machine:

[image]

The Windows 7 machine properties:

[image]

The Windows Server 2008 R2 machine properties:

[image]

Does somebody have an idea, why it does not compile on the Windows 7 machine, but compiles on the Windows Server 2008 R2 machine?

I have to compile it on the Windows 7 machine, without changing the code, or the project file. Therefore, I have to install, or configure something on the Windows 7 machine.

Comment: have you installed .net 3.5 sp1 under optional features?

Comment: Yes, on both machines .NET 3.5 is installed. I added the relevant Windows Features screenshots in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows Registry, I instructed .NET Framework 2.0 to look also for assemblies in the .NET Framework 3.0 folder. I put the following code into a file called DotNET3.0Compatiblity.reg:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\AssemblyFoldersEx\.NET 3.0 Compatiblity]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Reference Assemblies\\Microsoft\\Framework\\v3.0"
```

I double clicked the file, and the required registry entry was created.
You can see in the following picture, that the System.ServiceModel.dll is found now in the folder `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.ServiceModel.dll`.

[image: Project Test1.vbproj compiles without errors]